# UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.nio.ByteBuffer com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.load(long[], byte[], int, int)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, libgdx

So, i have this error happening and i don't understand. I'm converting pixmap to string here:

```
private fun convertPixmapToString(pixmap: Pixmap, name: String): String? {
        val image = Gdx.files.local("${name}.png")
        PixmapIO.writePNG(image, pixmap)

        val bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.file().absolutePath)
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)

        val b: ByteArray = baos.toByteArray()
        return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP)
    }
```

Then i convert it to pixmap to texture here:

```
private fun convertStringToTexture(encode: String): Texture {
        val decodedBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(encode, Base64.NO_WRAP)
        val pixmap: Pixmap = Pixmap(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.size)
        return Texture(pixmap)
    }
```

And i have this error when i try to covert it into pixmap: (the app crashes when i create the pixmap on "convertStringToTexture")

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.nio.ByteBuffer com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.load(long[], byte[], int, int) (tried Java_com_badlogic_gdx_graphics_g2d_Gdx2DPixmap_load and Java_com_badlogic_gdx_graphics_g2d_Gdx2DPixmap_load___3J_3BII)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.load(Native Method)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.<init>(Gdx2DPixmap.java:84)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:150)
```

The most bizarre is that i was using it earlier in a little bit different way, but i didn't change these methods, so what can it be?

PS: Libgdx is 1.11.0; java 8; i'm using kotlin on android studio

Comment: It means the JNI code isn’t loaded. One possible reason that I’ve often as the culprit here is trying to use native libGDX classes like Pixmap without first starting libGDX.

Comment: Alternatively, the JNI has been loaded ... but the native library doesn't implement that native method with those parameter types.  If so, you have a version mismatch between the Java class that declares the `native` method and the actual native library that was loaded.